# React.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First time using React.js.  Building ToDo app with React.js front end and Rails backend.  This is my tasks.js.jsx file:

```
"use strict";

var List = React.createClass({
    renderItems: function() {
        return _.map(this.props.tasks, function(task) {
            return <li className="list-group-item pointer" >{task.name}</li>;
        });
    },

    render: function() {
      return  <ul className="list-group">
                {this.renderItems()}
              </ul>;
    }
});

var Tasks = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      tasks: this.props.data
    }
  },

  getDefaultProps: function(){
    return {
      tasks: []
    }
  },

  renderList: function(complete){
    return <List tasks={_.filter(this.state.tasks, function(x) { return x.complete === complete; })} />;
  },

  render: function() {
    return  <div className="todos">
              <div className="incomplete-todo">
                <h1>Todo List</h1>
                <h2 className="spacing-bottom">Incomplete</h2>
                {this.renderList(false)}
              </div>
              <div className="complete-todo">
                <h2 className="spacing-bottom">Complete</h2>
                {this.renderList(true)}
              </div>
            </div>
  }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  React.render(<Tasks data={this.props.tasks}/>, document.getElementById('tasks'));
})
```

views/tasks/index.html.erb

```
<div id="tasks">
  <%= react_component 'Tasks', { data: @tasks } %>
</div>
```

controller/tasks_controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end
end
```

Although this code renders a list of my Tasks passed in from Rails.  I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined` on `<Tasks data={this.props.tasks}/>` and I don't know why.  On the other hand if I remove `data={this.props.tasks}` then this.props is undefined in all of my functions.  Does this have to do with the function componentWillMount?  If so, how do I call this function before the render?

Comment: Start with a console.log(this) and find out why props is not there, perhaps "this" is not the "this" you were counting on. Plus, I don't see any function or property of the Task class called props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was I was rendering twice:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  React.render(<Tasks data={this.props.tasks}/>, document.getElementById('tasks'));
});
```

I didn't need this at all.  Seems that the `<%= react_component 'Tasks', { data: @tasks } %>` in the index.html.erb file already calls render.  This was a time consuming lesson to learn.